# Python Plotly xaxis range to time between 09:00 to 15:30... Updating Plotly "layout" 'x-axis'?

Tags: pandas, datetime, plotly, range, python-3.9

I am trying to create a plotly chart for analysis of stocks in market hours (09:00 to 15:30).   I need help in setting the x-axis range for the entire day when the picture is being exported.   It currently shows the range to be exactly what is available in the 'csv' file.

However, at the start of the day, the exported chart jpg(1920x1080), is illegible until atleast midday(around 11:30am, because of the way it is ploted.)

See below Data, Code and Pic.

DATA in "some_stock.csv" at the start of the day...

```
TIME,open,high,low,close,Volume,RSI,rsi_30,rsi_70
2022-05-19 09:15:00,359.65,359.65,359.65,359.65,0,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:18:00,359.45,359.5,358.5,358.5,138161,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:21:00,358.6,358.75,358.45,358.7,96990,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:24:00,358.7,359.75,358.7,359.75,71892,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:27:00,359.75,359.9,359.25,359.9,64233,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:30:00,360,360.25,359.55,360.25,42732,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:33:00,359.6,360.4,359.6,359.75,103614,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:36:00,359.75,359.85,359.4,359.65,48508,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:39:00,359.85,359.85,359.45,359.5,22259,,30,70
2022-05-19 09:42:00,359.5,359.5,359.3,359.4,44802,,30,70
```

Code being Executed..

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## Creating a time range for that day in datetime format...
now_timeeee = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
string_start_time = now_timeeee+str(" 09:00:00")
start_timeeee = datetime.strptime(string_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
string_end_time = now_timeeee+str(" 15:30:00")
end_timeeee = datetime.strptime(string_end_time , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

## Graph Plotting...
df = pd.read_csv("some_stock.csv")

layoutt = go.Layout(autosize=False, width=1920, height=1368, title="some_stock")
fig_001 = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index, open=df["open"], high=df["high"], low=df["low"], close=df["close"], name="some_stock"), go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["RSI"], mode="markers+lines", name="RSI", yaxis="y2")], layout=layoutt).update_layout(yaxis_domain=[0.25, 1], yaxis2={"domain": [0, 0.20]}, xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, showlegend=True)
fig_001.update_xaxes(dict(range=[start_timeeee, end_timeeee]))
fig_001.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["rsi_30"], name = '30 line', yaxis="y2", line=dict(color='darkcyan', width=1)))
fig_001.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["rsi_70"], name = '70 line', yaxis="y2", line=dict(color='darkgreen', width=1)))
fig_001.write_image("images/fig_"+"some_stock"+".jpeg")
```

Exported Picture is as below.

[Exported Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVrXS.jpg)

Adding the line in the code doesnt do any difference to the x-axis which needs to be fixed for the range of 900hr to 1530hr

```
fig_001.update_xaxes(dict(range=[start_timeeee, end_timeeee]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found by changing

```
df = pd.read_csv("some_stock.csv")
```

to

```
df = pd.read_csv("ambujacem_3m.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

The problem was to read the dates as datetime and also, making it the index of the data.. Hence it seems to have resolved the issue..